How to get HTTP request headers in Ktor
I am using HttpClient from Ktor in my Kotlin project. How can I access the HTTP request headers? I know I can set them in the trailing HttpRequestBuilder lambda, but how do I see the headers that are currently set for the request (ideally before sending it)?

You can use the Logging plugin (https://ktor.io/docs/client-logging.html) to observe the request and response headers.

You can a phase to client's HttpRequestPipeline:
val phase = PipelinePhase("Headers check")
client.requestPipeline.addPhase(phase)
client.requestPipeline.intercept(phase) {
    println("Headers: ${context.headers.entries()}")
}

